# How to do bidirectional synchronization between multiple Redis severs

Tags: redis, synchronization, replication, bidirectional, redis-server

I am using multiple Redis servers , here one is master server and other one are replicas server. Suppose I wanna write something in master server then the changes will be reflected on replicas by default but if I make changes on either of replica then how the changes will reflect on master server. Please guide me how to do bidirectional synchronization. replica to master and vice versa

Here , master to replica synchronization is working fine but vice versa seems impossible

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.